# SQL SUM() values in model Joomla Component

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, model, joomla3.0

I have this function

```
public function getItem($idOn = false)
{
    if($idOn) {
        $id = $idOn;
    } else {
        $id = JRequest::getInt('id', $idOn);
    }
    if(!$id) return false;

    $select = $this->_db->getQuery(true);
    $select->select('a.*, b.title AS categoryTitle, c.email AS userEmail, SUM(s.view_item) AS hits');
    $select->from('#__cddir_content AS a');
    $select->join('INNER','#__cddir_categories AS b ON a.categories_id = b.id');
    $select->join('LEFT','#__users AS c ON a.users_id = c.id');
    $select->join('LEFT','#__cddir_statistic as s ON a.id=s.item_id');
    $select->where('a.id = '.$this->_db->quote($id));
    $select->where('a.published = 1');

    $user=JFactory::getUser();
    $aclgroups = implode(',', $user->getAuthorisedViewLevels());
    $select->where('a.access IN (' . $aclgroups . ')')
          ->where('b.access IN (' . $aclgroups . ')');

    $this->_db->setQuery($select);
    $item = $this->_db->loadObject();

    return $item;
}
```

I need to sum again the hits that I already added "SUM(s.view_item) AS hits", because some items have the same alias (a.alias) in #__cddir_content

So I need first sum all the s.view_items as hit that have the same id
Then I have to sum the saved hits that have the same alias.

I hope I made myself clear

Thank you for you help